# I am trying to do a jQuery remove based on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to remove an entire div and its content by using jquery

the value of the region will be entered into jquery after running a javascript function to find IP address here is the javascript find region from IP address

`$(document).ready(function() {
            $.get("https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=", function(data) {

                $("body").append("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data.location.region, "", 2) + "</pre>");`

So if data.location.region is texas then I want all the div class=m-s-a with region values not equal to texas to disappear.

So I need a jquery function I guess that takes in the region and does a removeClass.

Here is the sample body
`

```
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span `enter code here`class="region">Michigan</span> 48043</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">`enter code here`
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span class="region">Utah</span> 48043</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="for-sale-heading">
                <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span class="region">Texas</span> 48043</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".region").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "Texas") {
      $(this).closest(".m-s-a").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span class="region">Michigan</span> 48043</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span class="region">Utah</span> 48043</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="row m-s-a _hidden">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Auction:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Hard rock Cafe</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>Location:&nbsp;</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="for-sale-heading">
        <h4>4641 Production unit 42 Mt. Clemens, <span class="region">Texas</span> 48043</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This would have to be adjusted to your needs, e.g. instead of comparing the text of the `<span class="region">` to "Texas" you would compare it to `data.location.region` or the `<pre>` in which you added this region in your example - `$("pre").text()`, in case it's the only `<pre>` on your page.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to my answer to resolve your question as solved/answered.